# Possible decay process for a cubic scalar self-interaction and Yukawa interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, field-theory

Consider the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}h\partial^{\mu}h-\frac{1}{2}m^{2}h^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{3!}h^{3}$$

for a real scalar field $h$.

This is the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian with a cubic self-interaction term.

Does this model allow the decay process

$$h \rightarrow h + h?$$

Clearly, in the rest frame, the incoming scalar is at rest, so its total energy is its rest energy, and therefore, it cannot decay to two copies of itself (with twice the rest energy), as that would violate energy conservation?

**Edit to question based on answer:**

Okay, so if instead, we had the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}_{e}(i\gamma^{\mu}{\partial_{\mu}}-y_{e}\nu)\psi_{e}-y_{e}\bar{\psi}_{e}h\psi_{e}+\bar{\psi}_{\mu}(i\gamma^{\nu}{\partial_{\nu}}-y_{\mu}\nu)\psi_{\mu}-y_{\mu}\bar{\psi}_{\mu}h\psi_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}h)(\partial^{\mu}h)-\frac{1}{2}\left(2|\kappa^{2}|\right)h^{2}-\frac{\lambda}{6}\nu h^{3}-\frac{\lambda}{24}h^{4}$$

we can only write down processes like

$$h \rightarrow e^{-} + e^{+}, \qquad\qquad h \rightarrow e^{-} + e^{+} + e^{-} + e^{+}, \dots$$

$$h \rightarrow \mu^{-} + \mu^{+}, \qquad\qquad h \rightarrow \mu^{-} + \mu^{+} + \mu^{-} + \mu^{+}, \dots$$

$$h \rightarrow e^{-} + e^{+} + \mu^{-} + \mu^{+}, \dots $$

I was wondering if a particle (e.g. muon) must always be produced with its corresponding antiparticle (e.g. antimuon).

Also, I was wondering if there are only a finite number of processes for this reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, the decay can't happen. What's the question?

#### Edit

Yes, particles and antiparticles are produced in pairs

No, there's an infinite number of possible processes. What you write down are the most probable to happen.

Comment: see my edit, please!

Comment: @failexam done.

Comment: Regarding your second answer, if $h$ is the Higgs, then doesn't energy conservation place an upper limit on the number of electron-positron pairs that can be produced from Higgs decay?

Comment: @failexam it does, but processes like $h + e^{-} + e^{+} \rightarrow \dots$ are also possible

Comment: I am only considering the decay of the Higgs. Is $h + e^{-} + e^{+} \rightarrow \dots$ a decay of the Higgs?

Comment: @failexam then yes, there's a finite number of decay channels. You must have the sum of masses of particles on the right less than the mass of the Higgs.